# Compress image before upload to firebase on Web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a website developed in Angular 2, in which I allow users to upload images, as I can compress them before uploading them to Firebase, since most of my users upload very heavy files in the order of 2-3MB.

Comment: Take a look at this [generate-thumbnail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) sample that uses Cloud Functions to resize uploaded images.

Comment: tiny-png API can be useful. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull : [How to compress image files in angular 8 on the front end before upload](https://medium.com/@smihaylov1986/how-to-compress-image-files-in-angular-8-on-the-front-end-before-upload-e8b1c15d0714) . 
Anyway, you must always think of browser compatibilty and performance, if you want to do it on the front-end. It isn't always the best solution.